# Evaluating $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_{2n}}{n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, closed-form

I would appreciate to understand the main steps giving the evaluation of this series: $$ S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_{2n}}{n}$$ where $H_n$ is the harmonic number. I've tried with no success to obtain this sum with the help of Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: More generally, you can find $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_{kn}}{n}$$ in my paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/1010.1842

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using integral representation for harmonic number given by Leonhard Euler
\begin{equation}
H_k=\int_0^1\frac{1-x^k}{1-x}\,dx
\end{equation}
and Taylor series for natural logarithm
\begin{equation}
\ln(1+y)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\, (-1)^{k+1}\frac{x^k}{k}\qquad,\qquad\mbox{for}\,\,|y|<1
\end{equation}
we have
\begin{align}
S&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_{2n}}{n}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\int_0^1\frac{1-x^{2n}}{1-x}\,dx\\
&=\int_0^1\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\left[1-x^{2n}\right]\,\frac{dx}{1-x}\\
&=\int_0^1\left[\frac{\ln2-\ln\left(1+x^2\right)}{1-x}\right]\,dx\\
\end{align}
Now, apply integration by parts by taking $u=\ln2-\ln\left(1+x^2\right)$ and $dv=\dfrac{dx}{1-x}$. We obtain
\begin{equation}
S=-\lim_{t\to1}\left.\left[\ln2-\ln\left(1+x^2\right)\right]\ln(1-x)\right|_0^t-2\int^1_0\frac{x\ln(1-x)}{1+x^2}\,dx
\end{equation}
Since we have an indeterminate form $0\cdot\infty$ as $t\to1$, we may write our limit as
\begin{equation}
-\lim_{t\to1}\frac{\ln(1-t)}{\frac{1}{\ln2-\ln\left(1+t^2\right)}}
\end{equation}
then apply L'Hospital's rule twice to obtain
\begin{equation}
\lim_{t\to1}\left[\ln2-\ln\left(1+t^2\right)\right]\ln(1-t)=0
\end{equation}
Therefore, we may write our original sum as
\begin{equation}
S=-2\int^1_0\frac{x\ln(1-x)}{1+x^2}\,dx
\end{equation}
The evaluation of the latter integral can be seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1001269/133248). I take no credit for it. There are some good answers, but my personal choice is the answer using *differentiation under the integral sign* method since it's very simple and easy to understand. Anyway, this is a good question, thanks for sharing. ツ

Answer (score 9):

From the  [generating function for the harmonic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number), we immediately have that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{H_n}{n}z^n=\frac{1}{2}\log^2(1-z)+\operatorname{Li_2}(z)$$
and after multiplying both sides by $-2$ and setting $z=i$, we get 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}\frac{H_{2n}}{n}=-2\left(\frac{1}{2}\log^2(1-i)+\operatorname{Li_2}(i)\right)$$
$$=\frac{5\pi^2}{48}-\frac14 \ln^22$$

**Q.E.D.**

Comment: Please, I don't understand how you transform your first identity with $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{H_n}{n}z^{n}$$ to the second one $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{H_{2n}}{n}(-1)^{n}$$ just with $z:=i$. Thanks.

Comment: Mister Oloa, I said "after multiplying both sides by $-2$  and setting $z=i$", we get the second series. It's very easy to check since $i^n$ turns into $-1$ and $1$ on even powers, in an alternating way. (of course, we're interested in the real part)

Comment: The point is how do you switch from $H_n$ to $H_{2n}$? Thanks.

Comment: @OlivierOloa Just expanding the sum ... $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{H_n}{n}i^n=-\frac{H_2}{2}+\frac{H_4}{4}-\frac{H_6}{6}+\cdots+ i\left(\frac{H_1}{1}-\frac{H_3}{3}+\frac{H_5}{5}-\cdots\right)$$

Comment: @Chris'sis Thank you. Ok, I see it now!

Comment: @OlivierOloa If we multiply the equality above by $-2$, we have that 
$$-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{H_n}{n}i^n=\frac{H_{\large 2\cdot1}}{1}-\frac{H_{\large 2\cdot2}}{2}+\frac{H_{\large2\cdot3}}{3}-\cdots- i2\left(\frac{H_1}{1}-\frac{H_3}{3}+\frac{H_5}{5}-\cdots\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach to obtain

> $$
> \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_{2n}}{n}=\frac{5\pi^2}{48}-\frac14 \ln^22. \tag1
> $$

Recall the standard series expansion
$$
\log(1+z)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{z^{n}}{n},\quad |z|\leq 1, z\neq -1. \quad (*)
$$
Then, by the Cauchy product, one has
$$
\begin{align}
\log(1+z)\log(1-z)
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{z^{n}}{n}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{-z^{n}}{n}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k(n-k)}\right)z^{n}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\!\left( \frac{1+(-1)^{n}}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k}\right)\!z^{n}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{2n-1} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k}z^{2n}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\!\left( H_{2n}-H_n-\frac1n\right)\!z^{2n}\\
\end{align}
$$
equivalently
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{ H_{2n}}{n}z^{2n}=\log(1+z)\log(1-z)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{ H_{n}}{n}z^{2n}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{ 1}{n^2}z^{2n}
\end{align} \tag2
$$
Now, if you put $z:=i\,$ ($i^2=-1$) in $(2)$ you easily conclude with
$$
\begin{align}
& \log(1+i)=\log \left(\sqrt{2}\:e^{i\pi/4} \right)=\frac12 \ln2 + i\frac\pi 4 \\
& \log(1+i)\log(1-i)=\frac14 \ln^22+\frac{\pi^2}{16}\\
& \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{H_{n}}{n} =\frac{\ln^22}{2}-\frac{\pi^2}{12} \tag3\\
& \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^2} =-\frac{\pi^2}{12} \tag4
\end{align}
$$
giving the desired result.

---

We may prove $(3)$ by considering the standard identity, easily obtained from $(*)$,  $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}H_n x^{n-1} = -\dfrac{\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x)} \quad -1 < x<1,\,x\neq0,$$ integrating from $x=0^+$ to $x=1^-$ getting $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1} \dfrac{H_n}{n} \!= \!- \int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x)} dx = \!-\int_{0}^{1}\left(\dfrac{\ln(1+x)}{x}\! - \!\dfrac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x}\right) \! dx= -\dfrac{\pi^2}{12}+\dfrac{\ln^2 2}{2}$$ where we have classically used $(*)$ again to obtain $$\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{\ln(1+x)}{x}dx = \dfrac{\pi^2}{12}. $$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{S \equiv \sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n - 1}\,{H_{2n} \over n}}$

> With the [Harmonic Number Generating Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generating_functions)
>   $$
> -\,{\ln\pars{1 - x} \over 1 - x} = \sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}H_{n}x^{n} 
> $$

we'll have:
\begin{align}
-\,{\ln\pars{1 - x} \over 1 - x} &= \sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}H_{n}x^{n}
\\
-\,{\ln\pars{1 + x} \over 1 + x} &= \sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}H_{n}\pars{-x}^{n}
\\[5mm]
-\,{\ln\pars{1 - x} \over 1 - x} -{\ln\pars{1 + x} \over 1 + x}
&= 2\sum_{n\ =\ 1 \atop n\ \mbox{even}}^{\infty}H_{n}x^{n}
=2\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}H_{2n}x^{2n}
\\[5mm]
-\int_{0}^{x}\bracks{{\ln\pars{1 - t} \over 1 - t}
+{\ln\pars{1 + t} \over 1 + t}}\,{\dd t \over t}
&=\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}H_{2n}\,{x^{2n} \over n}
\end{align}

> We'll set $\ds{x = \ic}$ such that
>   \begin{align}
> S&=\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n - 1}\,{H_{2n} \over n}}
> =\int_{0}^{\ic}\bracks{{\ln\pars{1 - t} \over 1 - t}
> +{\ln\pars{1 + t} \over 1 + t}}\,{\dd t \over t}
> \\[5mm]&=\sum_{\sigma\ =\ \pm}\int_{0}^{\ic}
> {\ln\pars{1 - \sigma t} \over \pars{1 - \sigma t}t}\,\dd t
> =\sum_{\sigma\ =\ \pm}\bracks{\sigma\int_{0}^{\ic}
> {\ln\pars{1 - \sigma t} \over 1 - \sigma t}\,\dd t
> +\int_{0}^{\ic}{\ln\pars{1 - \sigma t} \over t}\,\dd t}
> \\[5mm]&=\sum_{\sigma\ =\ \pm}\bracks{-\,\half\,\left.\ln^{2}\pars{1 - \sigma t}
> \right\vert_{t\ =\ 0}^{t\ =\ \ic}
> +\int_{0}^{\sigma\ic}{\ln\pars{1 - t} \over t}\,\dd t}
> \\[5mm]&=\sum_{\sigma\ =\ \pm}\bracks{-\,\half\,\ln^{2}\pars{1 - \sigma\ic}
> -\int_{0}^{\sigma\ic}{\rm Li}_{2}'\pars{t}\,\dd t}
> \\[5mm]&=-\,\Re\bracks{\ln^{2}\pars{1 - \ic} + 2\,{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{\ic}}
> =\color{#66f}{\large -\,\Re\ln^{2}\pars{1 - \ic} - 2\,\Re{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{\ic}}
> \qquad\pars{1}
> \end{align}

However,
\begin{align}
\color{#00f}{\Re\ln^{2}\pars{1 - \ic}}
&=\Re\braces{\bracks{\half\,\ln\pars{2} - {\pi \over 4}\,\ic}^{2}}
=\color{#00f}{{1 \over 4}\,\ln^{2}\pars{2} - {\pi^{2} \over 16}}
\\[1cm]
\color{#00f}{\Re{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{\ic}}&
=\Re\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{\ic^{n} \over n^{2}}
=\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{\ic^{2n} \over \pars{2n}^{2}}
={1 \over 4}\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n} \over n^{2}}
\\[5mm]&={1 \over 4}\bracks{-\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{2n - 1}^{2}}
+\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{2n}^{2}}}
\\[5mm]&={1 \over 4}\bracks{-\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{2}}
+ \sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{2n}^{2}}
+\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{2n}^{2}}}
=-\,{1 \over 8}\ \underbrace{\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{2}}}
_{\ds{\color{#c00000}{\pi^{2} \over 6}}}\ =\ \color{#00f}{-\,{\pi^{2} \over 48}}
\end{align}

> With the previous partial result ( see expression $\pars{1}$ ) and these ones:
>   \begin{align}
> S &\equiv \color{#66f}{\large%
> \sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n - 1}\,{H_{2n} \over n}}
> =-\bracks{{1 \over 4}\,\ln^{2}\pars{2} - {\pi^{2} \over 16}}
> - 2\pars{-\,{\pi^{2} \over 48}}
> \\[5mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large{5\pi^{2} \over 48} - {1 \over 4}\,\ln^{2}\pars{2}}
> \approx {\tt 0.9080}
> \end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach:

We can see that for every $n≥k$, $\frac{1}{2k-1}+\frac{1}{2k}$ is included in $H_{2n}$. So we may conclude that:
$$
S=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left[\left(\frac{1}{2k-1}+\frac{1}{2k}\right)\cdot\sum_{n=k}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}\right]
$$
Now we have:
$$
\sum_{n=k}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}=\sum_{n=k}^{\infty} \left[(-1)^{n-1}\int_0^1 x^{n-1}dx\right]=\int_0^1 \left[\sum_{n=k}^{\infty} (-x)^{n-1}\right]dx=\int_0^1 \frac{(-x)^{k-1}}{1+x}dx
$$
And therefore:
$$
S=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left[\left(\frac{1}{2k-1}+\frac{1}{2k}\right)\cdot\int_0^1 \frac{(-x)^{k-1}}{1+x}dx\right]=\int_0^1 \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-x)^{k-1}}{2k-1}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-x)^{k-1}}{2k}}{1+x}dx
$$
And now:
$$
\arctan(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}x^{2k-1}}{2k-1} \implies \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-x)^{k-1}}{2k-1}=\frac{\arctan\left(\sqrt x\right)}{\sqrt x}
$$
$$
\ln(1+x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}x^k}{k} \implies \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-x)^{k-1}}{2k}=\frac{\ln(1+x)}{2x}
$$
Thus:
$$
S=\int_0^1 \frac{\frac{\arctan\left(\sqrt x\right)}{\sqrt x}+\frac{\ln(1+x)}{2x}}{1+x}dx=\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan\left(\sqrt x\right)}{\sqrt x(1+x)}dx+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x)}dx=\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan\left(\sqrt x\right)}{\sqrt x(1+x)}dx+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}-\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x}dx=\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan\left(\sqrt x\right)}{\sqrt x(1+x)}dx+{\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}}-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x}dx
$$
Now we can calculate the integrals. In the first one we can make the substitution $x\to \tan^2(x)$:
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan\left(\sqrt x\right)}{\sqrt x(1+x)}dx=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} 2(\tan(x)(1+\tan^2(x)))\frac{x}{\tan(x)(1+\tan^2(x))}dx=2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} x\space dx=\frac{\pi^2}{16}
$$
The second integral can be calculated as follows:
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}dx=\int_0^1 \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}x^{k-1}}{k}dx=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left[\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}\int_0^1 x^{k-1} dx\right]=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^2}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k-1)^2}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k)^2}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k)^2}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k)^2}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}-\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}-\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{12}
$$
The third we may calculate with partial integration:
$$
\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x}dx=\left[\ln^2(1+x)\right]_0^1-\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x}dx \iff \int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x}dx=\frac{1}{2}\left[\ln^2(1+x)\right]_0^1=\frac{\ln^2(2)}{2}
$$
So finally we have:
$$
S=\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan\left(\sqrt x\right)}{\sqrt x(1+x)}dx+{\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}}-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x}=\frac{\pi^2}{16}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\pi^2}{12}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\ln^2(2)}{2}=\frac{5\pi^2}{48}-\frac{\ln^2(2)}{4}
$$