# Prove $\int_0^1\frac{\ln2-\ln\left(1+x^2\right)}{1-x}\,dx=\frac{5\pi^2}{48}-\frac{\ln^22}{4}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

How does one prove the following integral

> \begin{equation}
> \int_0^1\frac{\ln2-\ln\left(1+x^2\right)}{1-x}\,dx=\frac{5\pi^2}{48}-\frac{\ln^22}{4} 
> \end{equation}

[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E1%5Cfrac%7B%5Cln2-%5Cln%5Cleft%281%2Bx%5E2%5Cright%29%7D%7B1-x%7D) and Mathematica can easily evaluate this integral. This integral came up in the process of finding the solution this question: [Evaluating $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_{2n}}{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1000140/133248). There are some good answers there but avoiding this approach. I have been waiting for a day hoping an answers would be posted using this approach, but nothing shows up. The integral cannot be evaluated separately since each terms doesn't converge. I tried integration by parts but the problem arises when substituting the bounds of integration.

I would appreciate if anyone here could provide an answer where its approach using integral only preferably with *elementary ways*.

Comment: Integrating by parts once yields $\displaystyle -\int^1_0\frac{2x\ln(1-x)}{1+x^2}{\rm d}x$, which should not be much of a problem for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will share two other possible methods that I happen to know of to compute this integral.

---

**Differentiation under the Integral Sign:**

Denote
$$\mathcal{I}(a)=\int^1_0\frac{-2x\ln(1-ax)}{1+x^2}{\rm d}x$$
Differentiating yields
\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}'(a)
=&\int^1_0\frac{2x^2}{(1+x^2)(1-ax)}{\rm d}x\\
=&-\frac{2}{1+a^2}\int^1_0\left(\frac{ax}{1+x^2}+\frac{1}{1+x^2}-\frac{1}{1-ax}\right) {\rm d}x\\
=&-\frac{a\ln{2}}{1+a^2}-\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{1}{1+a^2}-\frac{2\ln(1-a)}{a(1+a^2)}
\end{align}
Integrating back,
\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}(1)
=&\int^1_0\left(-\frac{a\ln{2}}{1+a^2}-\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{1}{1+a^2}-\frac{2\ln(1-a)}{a(1+a^2)}\right){\rm d}a\\
=&-\frac{1}{2}\ln^2{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}\arctan{1}+2{\rm Li}_2(1)-\int^1_0\frac{-2a\ln(1-a)}{1+a^2}{\rm d}a\\
=&\frac{5\pi^2}{24}-\frac{1}{2}\ln^2{2}-\mathcal{I}(1)
\end{align}
and a simple rearrangement yields
$$\color{red}{\mathcal{I}(1)=\frac{5\pi^2}{48}-\frac{1}{4}\ln^2{2}}$$

---

**Contour Integration:**

Contour integration is, admittedly, an extremely inefficient method to tackle this integral. Nevertheless, I will post this approach purely for the fun of it. 
Integrate $\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{\ln{2}-\ln(1+z^2)}{1-z}$ along a unit quarter circle in the first quadrant with indents at the pole $z=1$ and the branch point $z=i$. Both of the contributions from the indents tend to zero. Since the contour encloses no poles,
$$\int^1_0\frac{\ln{2}-\ln(1+x^2)}{1-x}{\rm d}x+\left(\int_{\text{arc}}+\int_{\text{line}}\right)\frac{\ln{2}-\ln(1+z^2)}{1-z}{\rm d}z=0$$
Around the arc,
\begin{align}
\Re\int_{\text{arc}}\frac{\ln{2}-\ln(1+z^2)}{1-z}{\rm d}z
=&\Re\int^\frac{\pi}{2}_0\frac{\ln{2}-\ln(1+e^{i2\theta})}{1-e^{i\theta}}ie^{i\theta}{\rm d}\theta\\
=&\frac{1}{2}\int^\frac{\pi}{2}_0\ln(\cos{\theta})\cot{\tfrac\theta 2}\ {\rm d}\theta-\frac{1}{2}\int^\frac{\pi}{2}_0\theta\ {\rm d}\theta\\
=&-\int^1_0\frac{2{\rm artanh}\ {t^2}}{t(1+t^2)}{\rm d}t-\frac{\pi^2}{16}\\
=&-\chi_2(1)+\frac{1}{4}\ln^2(1+t^2)\Bigg{|}^1_0-\int^1_0\frac{t\ln(1-t^2)}{1+t^2}-\frac{\pi^2}{16}\\
=&-\frac{3\pi^2}{16}+\frac{1}{4}\ln^2{2}-\frac{1}{2}\int^1_0\frac{\ln(1-t)}{1+t}{\rm d}t
\end{align}
Along the line segment on the imaginary axis,
\begin{align}
\Re\int_{\text{line}}\frac{\ln{2}-\ln(1+z^2)}{1-z}{\rm d}z
=&\Re\int^0_1i\frac{\ln{2}-\ln(1-y^2)}{1-iy}{\rm d}y\\
=&\int^1_0\frac{y\ln{2}}{1+y^2}{\rm d}y-\int^1_0\frac{y\ln(1-y^2)}{1+y^2}{\rm d}y\\
=&\frac{1}{2}\ln^2{2}-\frac{1}{2}\int^1_0\frac{\ln(1-y)}{1+y}{\rm d}y
\end{align}
Hence we have
$$\int^1_0\frac{\ln{2}-\ln(1+x^2)}{1-x}{\rm d}x=\frac{3\pi^2}{16}-\frac{3}{4}\ln^2{2}+\int^1_0\frac{\ln(1-x)}{1+x}{\rm d}x$$
For the sake of consistency only, I will use contour integration once again to evaluate the remaining integral though it can be computed easily with real methods. This time, integrate $\displaystyle g(z)=\frac{\ln(1-z)}{1+z}$ along a unit quarter circle with an indent at $z=1$. The contribution from the indent vanishes, hence leaving us with
$$\int^1_0\frac{\ln(1-x)}{1+x}{\rm d}x+\left(\int_{\text{arc}}+\int_{\text{line}}\right)\frac{\ln(1-z)}{1+z}{\rm d}z=0$$
Around the arc,
\begin{align}
\Re\int_{\text{arc}}\frac{\ln(1-z)}{1+z}{\rm d}z
=&\Re\int^\frac{\pi}{2}_0\frac{\ln(1-e^{i\theta})}{1+e^{i\theta}}ie^{i\theta}\ {\rm d}\theta\\
=&-\int^\frac{\pi}{4}_0\ln(2\sin{x})\tan{x}\ {\rm d}x-\frac{1}{4}\int^\frac{\pi}{2}_0\left(x-\pi\right)\ {\rm d}x\\
=&\frac{3\pi^2}{32}-\frac{1}{2}\ln^2{2}-\frac{1}{4}\underbrace{\int^1_0\frac{\ln{t}}{1+t}{\rm d}t}_{{\rm Li}_2(-1)}+\frac{1}{4}\int^1_0\frac{\ln(1+t)}{1+t}{\rm d}t\\
=&\frac{11\pi^2}{96}-\frac{3}{8}\ln^2{2}\\
\end{align}
Along the line segment on the imaginary axis,
\begin{align}
\Re\int_{\text{line}}\frac{\ln(1-z)}{1+z}{\rm d}z
=&\Re\int^0_1\frac{i\ln(1-iy)}{1+iy}{\rm d}y\\
=&-\int^1_0\frac{\arctan{y}}{1+y^2}{\rm d}y-\frac{1}{4}\int^1_0\frac{\ln(1+y)}{1+y}{\rm d}y\\
=&\left[-\frac{1}{2}\arctan^2{y}-\frac{1}{8}\ln^2(1+y)\right]^1_0\\
=&-\frac{\pi^2}{32}-\frac{1}{8}\ln^2{2}
\end{align}
Thus we have
$$\int^1_0\frac{\ln(1-x)}{1+x}{\rm d}x=-\frac{\pi^2}{12}+\frac{1}{2}\ln^2{2}$$
and consequently,
$$\color{red}{\int^1_0\frac{\ln{2}-\ln(1+x^2)}{1-x}{\rm d}x=\frac{5\pi^2}{48}-\frac{1}{4}\ln^2{2}}$$

Comment: I decide to comment for this time. Hey, you're a high-schooler & you're from Asia too, just like me. Do you have an email or accounts on Quora, Brilliant.org, or I&S that I can contact? I am interested in knowing more about you.

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova I am a relatively new user at I&S. However, I would prefer to keep the more personal details of my life such as my email private if you don't mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

We have:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} I &=& -\int_{0}^{1}\frac{2x \log(1-x)}{1+x^2}=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{2x^{k+1}}{1+x^2}\,dx=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{2}{k}\sum_{j=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{k+2j}\\&=&\sum_{j=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^{j+1}H_{2j}}{j}.\end{eqnarray*}\tag{1}$$
Since
$$\sum_{j=1}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2j-1}+\frac{1}{2j}\right)x^{j-1} = \frac{\operatorname{arctanh}\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac{\log(1-x)}{2x}$$
we have:
$$\sum_{j=1}^{+\infty} H_{2j}\, x^{j-1} = \frac{\operatorname{arctanh}\sqrt{x}}{(1-x)\sqrt{x}}-\frac{\log(1-x)}{2x(1-x)},$$
$$\sum_{j=1}^{+\infty} (-1)^{j+1}H_{2j}\, x^{j-1} = \frac{\arctan\sqrt{x}}{(1+x)\sqrt{x}}+\frac{\log(1+x)}{2x(1+x)},\tag{2}$$
hence:
$$ I = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan\sqrt{x}}{(1+x)\sqrt{x}}+\frac{\log(1+x)}{2x(1+x)}\,dx=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{2\arctan x}{1+x^2}\,dx+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(1+x)}{2x(1+x)}\,dx,$$
$$ I = \frac{\pi^2}{16}+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(1+x)}{2x}\,dx-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(1+x)}{2(1+x)}\,dx\tag{3}$$
and finally:

> $$ I = \frac{\pi^2}{16}+\frac{\pi^2}{24}-\frac{\log^2 2}{4}.$$

Comment: I think thats what the OP wanted to avoid, to bring it back to this harmonic sum.

Answer (score 3):

As M.N.C.E. stated in the comments, integrating by parts shows that $$ \begin{align} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log(2) - \log(1+x^{2}) }{1-x} \ dx&= - 2 \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x \log(1-x)}{x^{2}+1} \ dx \\ &= - 2 \ \text{Re} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log(1-x)}{x+i} \ dx . \end{align}$$

Letting $ \displaystyle t = \frac{x+i}{1+i} $,

$$ \begin{align} \int  \frac{\log(1-x)}{x+i} \ dx &= \int \frac{\log [(1+i)(1-t)]}{t} \ dt \\ &= \log(1+i) \int \frac{dt}{t} + \int\frac{\log(1-t)}{t} \ dt \ \ \left(- \pi < \frac{\pi}{4} + \text{Arg} (1-t) \le \pi \right) \\ &= \log(1+i) \log(t) - \text{Li}_{2} (t) + C  \\ &= \log(1+i) \log \left(\frac{x+i}{1+i} \right) - \text{Li}_{2} \left(\frac{x+i}{1+i} \right) + C . \end{align}$$

Therefore,

$$ \begin{align}  &\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log(2) - \log(1+x^{2}) }{1-x}  \\ &= - 2 \ \text{Re} \left[- \text{Li}_{2} (1) - \log(1+i) \log \left(\frac{1+i}{2}  \right) + \text{Li}_{2} \left(\frac{1+i}{2} \right) \right] \\ &= - 2 \ \text{Re} \left[- \frac{\pi^{2}}{6} - \left(\frac{\log 2}{2} + \frac{i \pi}{4} \right) \left(- \frac{\log 2}{2} + \frac{i \pi}{4} \right) \right] -2 \ \text{Re} \ \text{Li}_{2} \left(\frac{1+i}{2} \right)  \\ & = - 2 \left(\frac{\log^{2}(2)}{4} - \frac{5 \pi^{2}}{48} \right) - 2 \left(\frac{5 \pi^{2}}{96} - \frac{\log^{2} (2)}{8} \right) \\  &= \frac{5 \pi^{2}}{48} - \frac{\log^{2}(2)}{4} . \end{align}$$

To show that $$ \text{Re}  \  \text{Li}_{2} \left(\frac{1+i}{2} \right) = \frac{5 \pi^{2}}{96} - \frac{\log^{2} (2)}{8}$$ combine the [reflection formula for the dilogarithm (5)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html) with the property $\text{Li}_{n}(\bar{z}) = \overline{\text{Li}_{n}(z)}$.

Answer (score 3):

Start with subbing $x=\frac{1-y}{1+y}$

$$\mathcal{I}=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(2)-\ln(1+x^2)}{1-x}dx=\int_0^1\frac{2\ln(1+y)-\ln(1+y^2)}{y(1+y)}dy$$

$$=2\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+y)}{y}dy-2\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+y)}{1+y}dy-\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+y^2)}{y(1+y)}dy$$

$$=-2\operatorname{Li}_2(-y)|_0^1-\ln^2(1+y)|_0^1-\mathcal{J}$$

$$=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\ln^2(2)-\left(\frac{\pi^2}{16}-\frac34\ln^2(2)\right)=\boxed{\frac{5\pi^2}{48}-\frac14\ln^2(2)}$$

Where the last integral $\mathcal{J}=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+y^2)}{y(1+y)}dy$ can be proved using the common Feynman's method:

Let $$I(a)=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+a^2y^2)}{y(1+y)}dy, \quad I(0)=0, \quad I(1)=\mathcal{J}$$

$$I'(a)=\int_0^1\frac{2ay}{(1+y)(1+a^2y^2)}dy=2\frac{\tan^{-1}(a)}{1+a^2}+\frac{a\ln(1+a^2)}{1+a^2}-\ln(2)\frac{2a}{1+a^2}$$
$$\Longrightarrow \mathcal{J}=2\int_0^1\frac{\tan^{-1}(a)}{1+a^2}da+\int_0^1\frac{a\ln(1+a^2)}{1+a^2}da-\ln(2)\int_0^1\frac{2a}{1+a^2}da\\=\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)^2+\frac14\ln^2(2)-\ln^2(2)=\boxed{\frac{\pi^2}{16}-\frac34\ln^2(2)}$$

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{2} - \ln\pars{1 + x^{2}} \over
1 - x}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\int_{x\ =\ 0}^{x\ =\ 1}\bracks{\ln\pars{2} -
\ln\pars{1 + x^{2}}}\,\dd\ln\pars{1 - x}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{\mrm{IBP}}{=}\,\,\, &
\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{1 - x}\pars{-\,{2x \over 1 + x^{2}}}\,\dd x =
-2\int_{0}^{1}{x\ln\pars{1 - x} \over \pars{x + \ic}\pars{x - \ic}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
-\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{1 - x}\pars{{1 \over x + \ic} +
{1 \over x - \ic}}\,\dd x =
-\,\Re\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 - x} \over x + \ic}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,\Re\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over 1 + \ic - x}\,\dd x =
-\,\Re\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over 1 - x/\pars{1 + \ic}}
\,{\dd x \over 1 + \ic}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,\Re\int_{0}^{\pars{1\ -\ \ic}/2}{\ln\pars{\bracks{1 + \ic}x} \over
1 - x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] \stackrel{\mrm{IBP}}{=}\,\,\,&
-2\,\Re\int_{0}^{\pars{1\ -\ \ic}/2}{\ln\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
2\,\Re\int_{0}^{\pars{1\ -\ \ic}/2}\mrm{Li}_{2}'\pars{x}\,\dd x =
2\,\Re\,\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{1 - \ic \over 2}
\\[5mm] = &\
\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{{1 \over 2} - {1 \over 2}\,\ic} +
\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{{1 \over 2} + {1 \over 2}\,\ic}
\\[5mm] = &
{\pi^{2} \over 6} - \ln\pars{{1 \over 2} - {1 \over 2}\,\ic}
\ln\pars{{1 \over 2} + {1 \over 2}\,\ic}
\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}
In (\ref{1}) I used the
[Euler Reflection Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Dilogarithm).

---

Then,
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{2} - \ln\pars{1 + x^{2}} \over
1 - x}\,\dd x} =
{\pi^{2} \over 6} - 
\verts{-\,{1 \over 2}\,\ln\pars{2} - {1 \over 4}\,\pi\ic}^{\, 2}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{{5\pi^{2} \over 48} - {1 \over 4}\,\ln^{2}\pars{2}}
\approx 0.9080
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

In case the OP is curious about the harmonic series, here is an easy approach:

Using the classical identity

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} f(2n)=-\Re\sum_{n=1}^\infty i^n f(n)$$

then

$$S=\sum_{n-1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_{2n}}{n}=2\sum_{n-1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_{2n}}{2n}=-2\Re\sum_{n=1}^\infty i^n\frac{H_n}{n}$$

Using the generating function

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n\frac{H_n}{n}=\frac12\ln^2(1-x)+\operatorname{Li}_2(x)$$

Set $x=i$ we get

$$S=-2\Re\left(\frac12\ln^2(1-i)+\operatorname{Li}_2(i)\right)$$

$$=-2\Re\left(-\frac{5\pi^2}{96}-\frac18\ln^2(2)\right)=\frac{5\pi^2}{48}-\frac14\ln^2(2)$$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
&\int_0^1\frac{\ln2-\ln(1+x^2)}{1-x}{dx} \\
 =&\int_0^1\frac{\ln\frac2{1+x^2}}{1-x^2} \overset{x\to\frac{1-x}{1+x}}{dx}
+\int_0^1\frac{x\ln\frac2{1+x^2}}{1-x^2} \overset{x^2\to\frac{1-x}{1+x}}{dx}\\
=&\ \frac32\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}dx-\frac12\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{x}\overset{x^2\to x}{dx} -\frac12\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x}dx\\
 = & \ \frac54 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)}x dx
-\frac14\ln^2(1+x)\bigg|_0^1
= \frac{5\pi^2}{48}-\frac{1}{4}\ln^22
\end{align}
where $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x} dx =\frac{\pi^2}{12}$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}J&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln\left(\frac{2}{1+x^2}\right)}{1-x}\,dx\\
&\overset{y=\frac{1-x}{1+x}}=\int_0^1\frac{\ln\left(\frac{(1+x)^2}{1+x^2}\right)}{x(1+x)}\,dx\\
&=2\int_0^1\frac{\ln\left(1+x\right)}{x}\,dx-\ln^2 2+\int_0^1\frac{\ln\left(1+x^2\right)}{1+x}\,dx-\int_0^1\frac{\ln\left(1+x^2\right)}{x}\,dx
\end{align}In the last integral perform the change of variable $y=x^2$,
\begin{align}J&=\frac{3}{2}\int_0^1\frac{\ln\left(1+x\right)}{x}\,dx-\ln^2 2+\int_0^1\frac{\ln\left(1+x^2\right)}{1+x}\,dx\\
&=\frac{3}{2}\Big[\ln x\ln(1+x)\Big]_0^1-\frac{3}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1+x}\,dx-\ln^2 2+\Big[\ln(1+x)\ln\left(1+x^2\right)\Big]_0^1 -\int_0^1 \frac{2x\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}\,dx\\
&=-\frac{3}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1+x}\,dx-\int_0^1 \frac{2x\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}\,dx\\
A&=\int_0^1 \frac{2x\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}\,dx\\
B&=\int_0^1 \frac{2x\ln(1-x)}{1+x^2}\,dx\\
A+B&=\int_0^1 \frac{2x\ln(1-x^2)}{1+x^2}\,dx\\
&\overset{y=x^2}=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)}{1+x}\,dx\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)}{1+x}\,dx+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x}\,dx\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)}{1+x}\,dx+\frac{1}{2}\ln^2 2\\
&\overset{y=\frac{1-x}{1+x}}=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1+x}\,dx+\frac{1}{2}\ln^2 2\\
B-A&=\int_0^1 \frac{2x\ln\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)}{1+x^2}\,dx\\
&\overset{y=\frac{1-x}{1+x}}=\int_0^1 \frac{2(1-x)\ln x}{(1+x^2)(1+x)}\,dx\\
&=2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1+x}\,dx-\int_0^1 \frac{2x\ln x}{1+x^2}\,dx
\end{align}In the last integral perform the change of variable $y=x^2$,
\begin{align}B-A&=\frac{3}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1+x}\,dx\\\end{align}Therefore,
\begin{align}A&=\frac{1}{2}\Big((A+B)-(B-A)\Big)\\
&=-\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1+x}\,dx+\frac{1}{4}\ln^2 2\\
J&=-\frac{5}{4}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1+x}\,dx-\frac{1}{4}\ln^2 2\\
&=-\frac{5}{4}\left(\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1-x}\,dx-\int_0^1 \frac{2x\ln x}{1-x^2}\,dx\right)-\frac{1}{4}\ln^2 2\\
\end{align}In the second integral perform the change of variable $y=x^2$,
\begin{align}J&=-\frac{5}{8}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1-x}\,dx-\frac{1}{4}\ln^2 2\\
&=-\frac{5}{8}\times -\zeta(2)-\frac{1}{4}\ln^2 2\\
&=\boxed{\frac{5\pi^2}{48}-\frac{1}{4}\ln^2 2}
\end{align}
NB: I assume $\zeta(2)=\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$