# Even harmonic sums?

Tags: calculus, summation, harmonic-numbers

How do we calculate this?

$ \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} \frac{H_{2n}}{2n} $

I am stuck that the integrals isn't converging for harmonic (even) numbers . somebody please help .

Comment: Independently of what the solution is, note that the Harmonic numbers grow like $\log(n)$ and thus, as the sum is alternating, the series will converge, by the Leibniz test.

Comment: Yup I am also pretty convinced about the convergence , WA also supports but when I find the generating function of even harmonics and then integrate we fond a non-converging integral.

Comment: This question has different answers here:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1000140/evaluating-sum-n-1-infty-1n-1-frach-2nn

Comment: Oh thanks @OlivierOloa :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n - 1}\,\,{H_{2n} \over 2n}} & =
{H_{2} \over 2} - {H_{4} \over 4} + {H_{6} \over 6} - {H_{8} \over 8} + \cdots =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{H_{4n + 2} \over 4n + 2} -
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{H_{4n + 4} \over 4n + 4}
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{H_{n + 2} \over n + 2}
\,{1 + \pars{-1}^{n} + i^{n} + \pars{-\ic}^{n} \over 4} -
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{H_{n + 4} \over n + 4}
\,{1 + \pars{-1}^{n} + i^{n} + \pars{-\ic}^{n} \over 4} =
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}{H_{n} \over n}
\,{1 + \pars{-1}^{n} - i^{n} - \pars{-\ic}^{n} \over 4} -
\sum_{n = 4}^{\infty}{H_{n} \over n}
\,{1 + \pars{-1}^{n} + i^{n} + \pars{-\ic}^{n} \over 4}
\\[5mm] & =
-\,\half\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{H_{n} \over n}
\bracks{i^{n} + \pars{-\ic}^{n}} =
-\Re\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}H_{n}\,\ic^{n}\int_{0}^{1}x^{n - 1}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
-\Re\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}H_{n}\,\pars{\ic x}^{n}\,{\dd x \over x} =
\Re\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 - \ic x} \over x\pars{1 - \ic x}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
\color{#f00}{{5 \over 96}\,\pi^{2} - {1 \over 8}\,\ln^{2}\pars{2}} \approx
0.4540
\end{align}