# Is there a closed a form for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}H_{an}}{n}\,?$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, closed-form, harmonic-numbers

I am wondering if there is a closed form for

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}H_{an}}{n},$$

Where $a$ is positive real.

The integral representation of this sum is

$$a\zeta(2)+a\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x(1+x^a)}dx.$$

I encountered this sum while trying to generalize  [$\displaystyle\int_0^1 \frac{\ln \left( 1+x^{2+\sqrt{3}}\right)}{1+x}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/426325) to $\displaystyle\int_0^1 \frac{\ln \left( 1+x^{a}\right)}{1+x}dx.$

Thanks,

Comment: Have you already checked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2169507/calculating-alternating-euler-sums-of-odd-powers)? It's admittedly not quite what you want, since you want a slight modification of $\mathbf{H}_{1}^{(1)}(-1)$, but the techniques there are quite interesting for problems of this kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proof for $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_{2n}}{n} =\frac{5\pi^2}{48}-\frac14 \ln^22$$
can be found at [Evaluating $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_{2n}}{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1000140/269764), and in a comment there Omram Kouba provides the general result

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_{an}}{n}$$

via link to their paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/1010.1842. Specifically, it is there shown that:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_{an}}{n} = \frac{(a^2+1)\pi^2}{24a} - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{j=0}^{a-1} \log^2\left(2 \sin \frac{(2j+1)\pi}{2a} \right)$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the reference but unfortunately this formula works for only positive integer $a$ not positive real $a$.

Comment: @Ali Shadhar 1+ Nice problem, but very tough. I wonder if the case a=k+1/2 is possible

Comment: @Dr. Wolfgang Hintze thank you Wolf... I saw some article that there is a closed form for the integral in the question body for specific values of a.